# Make divs float from bottom in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to see if it is possible to float html DOM elements from bottom to top, rather than the usual top to bottom method.

By this method, what I am trying to do is when one div element is placed on top of other, and if we hide the top one realtime, I want the bottom one to float down the bottom itself, rather than floating up.

This is a working fiddle , http://jsfiddle.net/6XG87/1/  , if you click on "Hide Red", you can see the bottom blue element floating up. I have tried `vertical-align:bottom` in css, but that didnt work.

Is there anyother css methods to get this feature working?

Comment: so you want `blue` to stay in it position and do not shift up???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this setting

```
.outerContainer, .outerContainer div {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);    
    transform: scaleY(-1);    
}
```

(and removing align bottom.).

It makes the container be reversed, but the items are reversed againg so that they are facing upwards

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6XG87/9/)

You can also get this with the flex system, but support in older browsers is weak.

Answer (score 2):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6XG87/2/)**

**[demo1](http://jsfiddle.net/6XG87/7/)**

**css**

```
#inner2{
    height:80%;
    background:blue;
    vertical-align:bottom;
position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: This is a short term fix. What if I have more than 2 inner divs.. this solution will fail .. right?

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align:middle`

Use an outer layer to apply `position:absolute` because `table-cell` wont be aligning properly with absolute position.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class='outerContainer'>
    <div id='inner1'></div>
    <div id='inner2'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
       position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        left:100px;
    }
    .outerContainer{
        width:20px;
        height:200px;
        position:relative;
        display:table-cell;
        vertical-align:bottom;
        border:aqua 1px solid
    }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/IdegAnIY/2/)**